# How to retrieve http response headers using Excel Power Query

Tags: excel, http-headers, powerbi

I need to connect to a WebApi site using Excel power query.
The api has a login "EndPoint" that returns a cookie that needs to be used in a following request.

The following request is:

```
Web.Contents("http://www.example.com:8080/api/Consumption?startDate=2014-08-05&endDate=2014-08-06",
    [
        Headers=[#"Cookie" = "....."]
    ]),
```

How do i retrieve the cookie from the first response to be used in the second request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that it's currently not possible to have this kind of "step by step" custom authentication against an API within just PowerBI or PowerQuery.

For these scenarios we typically write a small "middleware" application that runs on a Infrastructure as a service backend, such as parse.com (shutting down) or firebase. The middleware then handles the authentication against the API. As the "source" in power Query / PowerBI we use our middleware, which basically just turns around to the API, handles the authentication and passes through the result.